# How to implement a GUI based Linux (XUbuntu) linux on arm Mac M1 processor

Tags: install, homebrew, java, ui, virtualbox

I want to install a software which predominantly uses GUI, and is available across all the platforms.

Interestingly, this software does not function properly on the Mac M1 natively, even with Rosetta. Therefore, I want to activate the GUI on a virtualization environment on a Linux Guest and Mac M1 host. I made the following **unsuccessful** attempts -

#### Attempt 1 With Virtualbox for M1 processors

In this attempt, I installed the VirtualBox beta version for M1/M2, then I used the Ubuntu ISO AMD 64 version; the installation did not proceed at all. It throws a hard disk error and shows something regarding UUID being unable to register.

#### Attempt 2 with Multipass

I was able to install Multipass with Homebrew and was able to activate the machine with the CLI. However, when I attempted to install the `xubuntu-desktop` and `xrdp` (as documented on Multipass's website, I was not able to gain access to the GUI interface.

#### Attempt 3 with UTM

I attempted to use the ARM-based distro of Ubuntu and yet there was no success even with this; it just fails to install.

Therefore, the farthest I have been able to go is to activate the CLI. How can I get the GUI to work on M1 on macOS?

---

### Screenshots of VirtualBox

[image: Im1]
[image: Im2]
[image: Im3]
[image: Im4]
[image: Im5]
[image: Im6]
[image: Im7]
[image: Im8]
[image: Im9]

Edit: Just to add, VirtualBox is working fine with Linux Guest and MacOS host on the Intel processor on another PC.

Comment: Firstly, I would ask the developers of the toolbox if they expect their software to work on ARM Macs. It may be that they have only built it for Intel.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are looking for in regard of answers: Do you need help with any of your attempts, do you need ideas about other approaches, or something else? Right now you seem to ask all at once which makes it difficult to answer your question (For example, "Use Parallels Desktop" is a valid answer to "How can I get the GUI to work on M1 on macOS?" but this is apparently not what you expected). You will get better answers by editing this question for focus or asking a specific one.

Comment: You are right. I am looking for FOSS based solutions.

Comment: What program is it that you want to run?

Comment: Another alternative might be to run the program under docker and use Xquartz as the X server running on the mac.

Comment: @mmmmmm I was trying to run the SNAP toolbox (Sentinel SNAP Toolbox used for Microwave Data Processing). I have been able to install with everyone's help the GUI for Linux. However, still the compiled version is not able to run on AARCH64. It appears that the code will need to be recompiled for the AARCH64.

Comment: @Indian - then you only current choice is UTM or docker and emulate Intel but it will be very slow. As I think it is all FOSS and mainly java then it should be compilable on ARM. Looking at https://senbox.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SNAP/pages/10879039/How+to+build+SNAP+from+sources those commands should be easy to do. ARM jdk and maven can come from Nomebrew or macports or possibly try tyhe non FOSS but still free version of Intellij

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is asking the wrong question for the user - the real question is how do I get SNAP to work on a M1 Mac. The answer really is ask the developers

Comment: @mmmmmm Well, the question still has merits, even if the answers won't solve the actual problem the OP has.

Answer (score 3):

From the nature of your question, it seems like you want first of all an easy to use solution for first time users. In that case, I would suggest [Parallels Desktop](https://www.parallels.com/).

There is a free, 14-day trial version. The full version of the software costs €99.99 for home users.

After installing Parallels Desktop, you can select to create a new virtual machine. You will be given the choice of automatically installing included, ready-to-go Linux distributions for ARM. You can choose from Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian and Kali.

This will give you a full installation of Linux - including the GUI - and you do not have to know how to install Linux. It is done automatically.

**UPDATE:**

From your comments, you indicate that you are not a first time user of VirtualBox. In that case, I would again recommend Parallels Desktop, but if you must go with VirtualBox then remember to download the ARM64 version of Ubuntu.

You list in the question that you have tried installing the AMD64 version of Ubuntu in VirtualBox on the M1 Mac. That will not work, as it requires an Intel-compatible CPU in order to work. You can install it using CPU-emulation, but that would not be workable in practice. Use the ARM64 version and you'll get (more than) decent performance.

Comment: I have been using VirtualBox since the last 15 years, for connecting Linux and other Operating Systems (Windows). I know how to install linux, and shell programming. However, as I told you the GUI isnt working, the SSH via the `ssh -X IP` fails to even connect on Multipass.

Comment: In that case I would go back to your attempt #1 and try again. You choose the incorrect version of Ubuntu to install, and that's why it failed. You do not want the AMD64 version, as that is for Intel-compatible CPUs. You want the ARM64 version.

Comment: AFAIK ARM support for Ubuntu only is available in the Server version.

Comment: Yes, I know - but the server edition can have a GUI as well. Just install the ubuntu-desktop package via apt.

Comment: The screenshots are included now in the question.

Comment: You have set it up for an unattended (i.e. automatic) setup - don't do that. VirtualBox can't do that for ARM Linux on M1 yet. Do a manual setup instead - this way you can also see for yourself if there's any error messages displayed.

Comment: Update on the discussion here. So VirtualBox Beta for M1 / M2 is not able to boot from the ARM64 distro (neither attended nor unattended) [The failure screenshot is provided in the original question]. I tried to do the same with UTM and I was able to install and launch the GUI within the VM.

Comment: UTM is an emulator as well as a virtualizer that is it can emulate different processors e.g. Intel on Arm (or PPC on ARM) VirtualBox is only an VM and so can only run for the same processor as the host. NB emulation is slow so you don't want it in this case.

Comment: A quick look at this bug https://senbox.atlassian.net/browse/SNAP-1571 says it is running on ARM Ventura so ask in the forums for help - someone does have it working

Answer (score 0):

There is a project to build a Linux version designed for Apple Silicon Macs, called Asahi Linux.

You may have more luck with this on the bare metal.

https://asahilinux.org/about/

Comment: This is not a good idea - Asahi Linux specifically does not run in virtual machines on Apple Silicon Macs. It only runs on bare metal.